# Problemas com consultas sem refresh de tela

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, post, keyup

Amigos, estou tentando fazer uma busca no banco de dados e apresentar o resultado na tela sem que seja preciso atualizar a pagina, porem ao digitar no input nenhuma mensagem é exibida.

O usuário começaria digitar um nome e os nomes similares ao digitado deveriam aparecer na tela.

Estou usando um código que vi em um tutorial e por isso não tenho muita certeza do que ele esta fazendo, mesmo sendo um código bem simples.

Esse é o trecho do meu HTML:

```
<div class="pess_painel" id="pess_ajusta_painel">
    <h1 class="display-2">Ficha do Aluno</h1>
    <h4 >Você pode buscar um aluno cadastrado ou cadastrar um novo para abrir a página dele</h4>
        <div class="pess_centralizar pess_tipo_ajuste">
            <div class="pess_item_div">
                <input type="text" name="getAluno" class="form-control pess_centralizar" id="getAluno" placeholder="Buscar Aluno" required>
            </div>
            <p>ou</p>
            <div class="pess_item_div">
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-block"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addAlunoModal">Cadastrar Novo Aluno</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    <ul class="aluno_resultado">
      
    </ul>
</div>
```

Esses são os scripts usados:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.11/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/PascaleBeier/bootstrap-validate/v2.2.0/dist/bootstrap-validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

Essa é a minha função, que deveria atualizar a tela com os resultados da consulta:

```
$(function(){
  $("#getAluno").keyup(function(){

    var pesquisa = $(this).val();
    if (pesquisa != '') {
      var dados = {
        palavra : pesquisa
      }
      $.post('busca_alunos.php', dados, function(retorna){
              
        $(".aluno_resultado").html(retorna);
      });
    }else{
      $(".aluno_resultado").html('');

    }
  });
});
```

E a seguir o arquivo busca_alunos.php, nele por enquanto, não exibo o retorno da consulta, estou exibindo apenas uma mensagem padrão dizendo se encontrou ou não o cadastro.

```
<?php
require_once 'verifica.php';
require_once 'conexao2.php';

    $alunos = $_POST['palavra'];

    global $pdo;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ALUNOS where NOME LIKE :nome  ";
    $sql = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $sql->bindValue(':nome', "%".$alunos."%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
    
    $sql->execute();


    if($sql->rowCount() <= 0){
        echo "Nenhum Aluno Encontrado.";
    }else{
        echo "Aluno Encontrado";
    }  
?>
```

Comment: Pessoal, tem algum problema na minha pergunta, se tiver me informem por favor para que eu possa reformular a mesma e tentar melhorar, pois 'negativaram' a minha pergunta mas não informaram a razão, logo não sei como melhorar e pergunta para que alguem posa de fato me ajudar com a duvida.

Comment: Boa noite amigo, retorna algum erro?

Comment: Bom dia Eduardo, não retorna erro algum, por isso que esta dificil identificar o que de fato esta ocorrendo, mas nos meus testes da a entender que o problema esta aqui `$.post('busca_alunos.php', dados, function(retorna)` pois coloquei umas mensagens de teste dentro do busca_alunos.php e nenhuma das mensagens foi exibida nos meus testes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema ocorria por conta de um conflito gerado com essa importação `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>`

Após remover esse script o meu código funcionou perfeitamente.